# How to group data based on the scatter plot from Panda plotted figure

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to group into two categories. I used panda get a scatter plot of my data. See the figure, I want all the data in the left upper corner to be a group and the remaining data into a secondary group. How can I sort my data based on the plotted figure?
Thanks for any help!

```
index x       y
11  86.58   3.31
26  128.79  2.79
46  43.34   6.32
71  95.39   3.90
72  93.95   3.40
73  117.76  3.06
75  82.37   3.83
```

.............

```
g=sns.jointplot(x='x',y='y',data=GA_m_W,space = 0.1,ratio = 3)
```

[figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s13vR.png)

Comment: your question sounds more like machine learning, are you trying to group the data according to its features???

Comment: Sounds like you  need a clustering algorithm, if you want to do this generically. For this specific case, you can draw a diagonal line which divides the data how you want, and find the equation for that line (y = mx + b). Then, for each data point, assign it a group based on whether it is above or below the line.

Comment: Thank you very much for you reply. I don't think it is machine learning problem. I  have the original data and its scatter plot. I just want to know the index numbers of the points in the left upper corner?

Comment: Thank you @n3utrino . I will try your method.

Comment: for this specific case, you can even see that every point with `y` above 5 (or 5.1 maybe) is the upper group (something like `df.loc[df['y'] >5]` would select this group) and the one with `y` less than 5 it's the lower group, a bit like said @n3utrino but this case is really simple I think